# How use Integer / string in EnumPropery items

Tags: python

I have EnumProperty, and i need an integer number when i select my "Mode"

Now i have:

```
item = (
    ('Mode 1', "Mode 1", ""),
    ('Mode 2', "Mode 2",""))
```

but i need:

```
item = (
    (1, "Mode 1", ""),
    (2, "Mode 2",""))

class MyProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_menu = EnumProperty(items = item)
```

but give error

Comment: check this reference: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem.html#bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem

Comment: As pointed out enum identifiers are type string. Can you elaborate on why you _need_ it to be an int?

Comment: @batFINGER Right, i need integer because this script control parameter , that parameter accept only an integer, but now by Hikariztw i can transform "1" (string) in 1 (Integer) by int("1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `EnumPropertyItem(bpy_struct)` only accept *String* as **identifier**,
you can use Python built-in `int()` and `str()` to convert between *String* and *Integer*.

A Quick example:

```
a = 13
int(str(a)) is 13 # True
```